# TypeError: _client_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.fetch is not a function. How to solve this problem?

Tags: reactjs

I was using react hooks face this error blew.

import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import sanityClient from '../client.js'

```
 export default function Post() {
 const [postData, setPost] = useState(null);
   7 | 
   8 |    useEffect(() => {
>  9 |        sanityClient.fetch(
     | ^  10 |                  `*[_type == "post"]{
  11 |                  title,
  12 |                  slug,
                    mainImage{
                      asset => {
                          _id,
                          url
                      },
                      alt
                  }
              }`
        )
        .then((data) => setPost(data))
        .catch(console.error);
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after checking my code I found multiple error
like:

- importing sanityClient from "@sanity/client" (that is not your case)
- ``` mainImage{asset => {_id, url }, should be ``mainImage{asset -> {_id, url } ```with the dash and not with equal

so my suggest have a double check of your spelling

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you import sanity client, you have no Brackets (see below):

- import  sanityClient  from "@sanity/client";
- also, asset=> should be asset->